# Low resolution on 4K monitor

Tags: resolution

Am I missing a step in how to get my 4K monitor outputting in 4K resolution (or even 1080!)?

I've just made a fresh install of Ubuntu (14.04.1 LTS) and both my monitors are detected and outputting a display - my secondary monitor correctly gives it's max resolution of 1920x1080. However, the primary monitor (Samsung LU28D590DS) is only giving three available settings (graphics card is AMD R9 290X):

- 800x600
- 832x624
- 1024x768

Previously I was having no problems when I installed Ubuntu through Virtualbox - I just had to submit the below command to get it working so not sure why it would be a problem now?:

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms`

Comment: Do you have the proprietary drivers fglrx installed? Open Source drivers would probably have not work correctly with multi-monitor setup.

Comment: Thanks @DanJohansen - I had no idea there was such as thing as  fglrx - worked perfectly! Wish I could accept your reply as an answer but thank you all the same :)